# Error Message System.QueryException: List has no rows for assignment to SObject :Stack Trace Class.CloneContractCtrlr.<init>: line 18, column 1

Tags: apex

HI friends i need little help to resolve this error

```
public CloneContractCtrlr(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
        //objCntrct= new Contract();

     objCntrct= new Contract();
     String recId = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('conid');

     objCntrct = [Select Id, Name, Opportunity__c,Forecast_Date__c,Capital_Business_Owner__c,OwnerId  FROM Contract where id =:recId limit 1];          
     system.debug('objCntrct--ct--'+objCntrct); 

   objCntrct.Capital_Business_Owner__c = objCntrct.OwnerId;                       

  //system.debug('objCntrct123----'+objCntrct.Capital_Business_Owner__c); 

}
```

Comment: Hi @karunakar welcome to SFSE. Please take some moments to read [ask] and our [help center].

Answer (score 0):

Store your results from the SOQL in a List. If you are using a limit on the query, you know that the first position of this collection is the record you want to use.

```
public CloneContractCtrlr(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {

 Contract objCntrct= new Contract();
 String recId = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('conid');

 List<Contract> objCntrct = [Select Id, Name, Opportunity__c,Forecast_Date__c,Capital_Business_Owner__c,OwnerId  FROM Contract where id =:recId limit 1];          
 system.debug('objCntrct--ct--'+objCntrct); 

 if (objCntrct.size() > 0) {
     objCntrct[0].Capital_Business_Owner__c = objCntrct[0].OwnerId;
 }                       

//system.debug('objCntrct123----'+objCntrct.Capital_Business_Owner__c); 

}
```

Please see [this](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/apex_database/apex_database_soql) Trailhead which focuses on SOQL.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This code will throw a nullPointer exception. If there are no objects, you won't have a object on `objCntrct[0]`

Comment: Hit save too soon before finishing the entire answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your SOQL query doesn't return any row,

Check that your getParameters().get('conid'); returns the expected output and that it is a Contract Id.

To do so you can just debug your recId :

```
System.debug('conid :' + recId);
```

Also I'd suggest you use an Id and not a String to store it :

```
Id recId = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('conid');
```

Comment: hi @Pierrick can you improve your answer by providing a way to do that validation?

Answer (score 0):

Add **Id** parameter with Contract record Id on your visualforce page.

Example:
`ContractId = '800xxxxxxxxxXXX'`

*'/apex/SamplePage?id=800xxxxxxxxxXXX'*